# Setting user permissions on a directory located inside of a root directory (spack package manager)

Tags: software-installation, permissions

I am currently trying to use a package manager called [spack](https://github.com/spack/spack). I am using the following commands to clone it into a directory that otherwise only has r+w+x permissions for root users and r permissions for the current user:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/spack/spack.git
sudo chgrp -R my_user_group spack
sudo chmod -R +rwx spack
```

When I try to install a package, I get the error message

```
==> Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/my/root/directory/spack/opt'
```

The `spack/opt` directory is usually created at runtime when it doesn't exist yet. Right now, I get a Permission denied error while trying to access a nonexistent folder, which means that the create command didn't go through. I thought that setting r+w+x permissions for that particular group like this was enough to do that, am I missing a step in order to be able to freely use this directory as a user from `my_user_group`?

Comment: Is this an Ubuntu system and if so what version?

Answer (score 0):

Setting permissions to `sudo chmod -R 777` solved the issue in this case.